# Why is my string truncated when copied?

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I'm trying to find whether `less` is installed using `C` (with no use of system calls). But there is something wrong with my copying of the variable. The contents of the string is truncated:

```
 int ret;
 char * pathValue;
 char * pathValue2;
 char *token3;
 char * new_str ;
 int pathlength;
 pathValue = getenv ("PATH");
 if (! pathValue) {
    printf ("'%s' is not set.\n", "PATH");
 }
 else {
    printf ("'%s' is set to %s.\n", "PATH", pathValue);
 }

 pathlength = sizeof(pathValue)/sizeof(char);
 pathValue2 = malloc(sizeof(pathValue));
 strncpy(pathValue2, pathValue, pathlength);
 printf ("pathValue2 is to %s.\n", pathValue2);
 token3 = strtok(pathValue2, ":");
 ret = 1;
 printf("Looking for less\n");
 while( token3 != NULL ) {
    printf("Looking for less %s\n", token3);

    if((new_str = malloc(strlen(token3)+strlen("/less")+1)) != NULL) {
        new_str[0] = '\0';
        strcat(new_str,token3);
        strcat(new_str,"/less");
        printf( " %s\n", new_str );
        if (file_exist (new_str)) {
            printf("Found less\n");
            ret=0;
        }
        free(new_str);

    } else {
        printf("malloc failed!\n");
    }

    token3 = strtok(NULL, ":");
 }

 free(pathValue2);
```

If I run the program, the first variable is my correct `PATH` but when I have copied it, it has become truncated. What is wrong here?

> ```
> $ ./a.out 
> 'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games.
> pathValue2 is to /usr/loc.
> Looking for less
> Looking for less /usr/loc
>  /usr/loc/less
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe, the problem is here

```
pathlength = sizeof(pathValue)/sizeof(char);
```

In this case, `pathValue` is a pointer and `sizeof(pathValue)` will produce a value of only the size of the pointer, not the *whole amount of memory occupied by the string*.

What you want here is to use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) instead.

Also, as mentioned in the below comment, C standard guarantees that `sizeof(char)` will always produce a value of `1`. so, it can be dropped from the calculation./

Comment: And there is no way that `sizeof(char) != 1`.

Comment: @moffeltje somehow I managed to spot the mistake faster. Usually, it's a common one. :-)

Comment: It's good that you say **produce**, because `sizeof()` doesn't **return**, since it's an operator, I just answered a question and erroneously said `returned`, I left it like that because no aprropriate word came to my mind.

Comment: @iharob somehow I also did the same in the first occurrence, corrected now. :-)